# 自分のサイトの取引ステータスとPayPalの取引ステータスを同期する方法

Tags: paypal

PayPalにおいて、自分のサイトの取引ステータスとPayPal上の取引ステータスを同期する方法はありますでしょうか。
取引ステータスだけではなく、PayPalから取引の詳細を取得し、自分のウェブサイトのバックエンドシステムをいろいろ更新したいのですが、その機能はどう設定するのでしょうか？

Comment: あなたの質問(出来たら全て)の自己回答の承認をお願いしたいです。よろしくお願いいたします。

Answer (score 0, accepted):

マーチャントのウェブサイトの取引ステータスとPayPalの取引ステータスを同期するには、即時支払い通知(IPN)サービスを利用してください。
即時支払い通知(IPN)は、リアルタイムでの購入確認を処理するためのPayPalの決済APIです。IPNを使用して、ソフトウェアのダウンロード、ユーザーログイン、およびその他のPayPal対応のウェブサービスおよび通信を管理できます。IPNを使用すると、お客さまのサーバーに取引詳細を送信することによって、PayPal支払いをいつ受け取っても取引のステータスがいつ変更されても、業務の特定部分を自動的に処理できます。
通常はマーチャントのサイトでプログラム（IPNリスナー）を作成してIPNメッセージを解析して、サイト上の注文ステータス更新やほかの決済後の処理をします。
IPN機能の詳細とIPNリスナー作り方は下記のアドレスをご参考ください：
https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/classic/ipn/integration-guide/IPNIntro/
IPNリスナーサンプルコード
https://github.com/paypal/ipn-code-samples

PayPalではテクニカルサポートの部署がありますので、何かPayPal実装関連の質問や技術的な質問がありましたら、下記URLで記事を検索してみてください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/
上記URLの一番下の「お問い合わせ」リンクをクリックしてまたは下記URLをアクセスして質問を送信してください。
https://jp.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask